# Invalid argument on fsck of a 2GB VFAT filesystem

Tags: linux, fsck

I wanted to run fsck to repair a VFAT filesystem on a 2GB SD card, on Fedora 12.  I got an 'invalid argument' error as seen below.  What does it mean in this context?  Is it not possible to check a filesystem on a SD card?

```
$ fsck -t vfat /dev/sdd1
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.16.2
dosfsck 3.0.9, 31 Jan 2010, FAT32, LFN
Seek to 2031225344:Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in dosfsck:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693662

Apparently, no update for Fedora 12.

Some more info can be found here:
http://daniel-baumann.ch/gitweb/?p=software/dosfstools.git;a=blob;f=ChangeLog;hb=0d2c9bcd6ac21d1ef6fab5b563334fe1e1f743ba#l655

Consider compiling newer version from the sources or grab the rpm from Daniel's page.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

backup information, reparted and reformated sd card.
or try windows System File Checker(fsc)

Comment: Well, I can not copy the files because the file system seems damaged.   I wanted to try bringing it to an usable state so I can copy things off it.

Comment: I think you may have meant chkdsk, rather than System File Checker.